# Wordpress: loop through post with custom field

Tags: wordpress

I loop through posts and by category_name=news, How can I display each post's custom field? thank you in advance.

```
<?php $preNewsPosts = new WP_Query();
$preNewsPosts->query('posts_per_page=3&category_name=news');
while($preNewsPosts->have_posts()): $preNewsPosts->the_post();
?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="atitle" ><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php
the_excerpt();
?>
<hr style="width: 95%; border: 1px solid #e6e6e6; " />
<?php
endwhile;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, just place inside the `while` loop. Make sure you change `custom_field` to the name of your custom field

```
echo get_post_meta($preNewsPosts->post->ID, 'custom_field', true);
```

Comment: you might want to add `global $post;` as well

Comment: since your are using `wp_query` you can/should get id by using `$preNewsPosts->post->ID`.. no need for global $post

Comment: Big thanks to all! I put the `echo get_post_meta($preNewsPosts->post->ID, 'location', true);` right after excerpt() but it didn't work. And I have numbers of custom fields I want to display, can I loop through it without specifying the custom fields name?